# Deploy React Starter Kit (by Kriasoft) to Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I've been trying to deploy the original demo of React Starter Kit found on `https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit` to Heroku with no success until just now.

What I've done is just clone the repo, then use `heroku create` and then `git push heroku master` to deploy. But every time I open the app now hosted by Heroku, it shows an Application Error. I also tried `npm run deploy` to no avail.

Then I found a React Starter Kit buildpack here: `https://github.com/angelhive/react-starter-kit-buildpack` and used it instead of the official Node.js buildpack and BAM! It worked!

My question is: this custom buildpack has zero stars on GitHub so I take it most people using the React Starter Kit don't use it.

So how do you deploy to Heroku then?

---

**Update 24 Oct 2016:**

This is the error log I'm getting after running `heroku logs` on a React Starter Kit app without the custom buildpack I've mentioned. `NODE_ENV` is set to `production` and the dynos correctly run a `web: npm start` command.

```
2016-10-24T16:58:59.080046+00:00 heroku[api]: Enable Logplex by XXXXXXXXXXX
2016-10-24T16:58:59.080092+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v2 created by XXXXXXXXXXX
2016-10-24T17:00:10.139875+00:00 heroku[api]: Set NODE_ENV config vars by XXXXXXXXXXX
2016-10-24T17:00:10.139974+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by XXXXXXXXXXX
2016-10-24T17:00:35.563970+00:00 heroku[api]: Scaled to web@1:Free by XXXXXXXXXXX
2016-10-24T17:00:35.567139+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 048e67f by XXXXXXXXXXX
2016-10-24T17:00:35.567139+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v4 created by XXXXXXXXXXX
2016-10-24T17:00:36.222028+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-10-24T17:00:36.222047+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-10-24T17:00:38.552446+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-10-24T17:00:42.185504+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-10-24T17:00:42.185533+00:00 app[web.1]: > @ start /app
2016-10-24T17:00:42.185534+00:00 app[web.1]: > babel-node tools/run start
2016-10-24T17:00:42.185535+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-10-24T17:00:42.192826+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: babel-node: not found
2016-10-24T17:00:42.200552+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-10-24T17:00:42.210421+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-100-generic
2016-10-24T17:00:42.210728+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-10-24T17:00:42.210968+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v5.11.1
2016-10-24T17:00:42.211330+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2016-10-24T17:00:42.211141+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
2016-10-24T17:00:42.211525+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2016-10-24T17:00:42.211735+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2016-10-24T17:00:42.212382+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2016-10-24T17:00:42.212551+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! @ start: `babel-node tools/run start`
2016-10-24T17:00:42.212706+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2016-10-24T17:00:42.212849+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2016-10-24T17:00:42.212995+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script 'babel-node tools/run start'.
2016-10-24T17:00:42.213144+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2016-10-24T17:00:42.213569+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2016-10-24T17:00:42.213288+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
2016-10-24T17:00:42.213424+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-10-24T17:00:42.213724+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     babel-node tools/run start
2016-10-24T17:00:42.213831+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2016-10-24T17:00:42.214003+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs 
2016-10-24T17:00:42.214094+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2016-10-24T17:00:42.214241+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls 
2016-10-24T17:00:42.214386+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2016-10-24T17:00:42.220413+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-10-24T17:00:42.220613+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-10-24T17:00:42.220727+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-10-24T17:00:42.305908+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-10-24T17:00:42.306806+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-10-24T17:00:42.287610+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-10-24T17:00:44.933721+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2016-10-24T17:00:49.345711+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-10-24T17:00:49.345725+00:00 app[web.1]: > @ start /app
2016-10-24T17:00:49.345726+00:00 app[web.1]: > babel-node tools/run start
2016-10-24T17:00:49.345726+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-10-24T17:00:49.354255+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: babel-node: not found
2016-10-24T17:00:49.361940+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-10-24T17:00:49.372282+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-100-generic
2016-10-24T17:00:49.372554+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-10-24T17:00:49.372733+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v5.11.1
2016-10-24T17:00:49.372926+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
2016-10-24T17:00:49.373115+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2016-10-24T17:00:49.373304+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2016-10-24T17:00:49.373492+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2016-10-24T17:00:49.373868+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! @ start: `babel-node tools/run start`
2016-10-24T17:00:49.373697+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2016-10-24T17:00:49.374022+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2016-10-24T17:00:49.374201+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2016-10-24T17:00:49.374376+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script 'babel-node tools/run start'.
2016-10-24T17:00:49.374678+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
2016-10-24T17:00:49.374528+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2016-10-24T17:00:49.374822+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-10-24T17:00:49.374977+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2016-10-24T17:00:49.375126+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     babel-node tools/run start
2016-10-24T17:00:49.375284+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2016-10-24T17:00:49.375746+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls 
2016-10-24T17:00:49.375448+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs 
2016-10-24T17:00:49.375600+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2016-10-24T17:00:49.381159+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-10-24T17:00:49.375892+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2016-10-24T17:00:49.381402+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-10-24T17:00:49.381546+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-10-24T17:00:49.475744+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-10-24T17:00:49.480202+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-10-24T17:00:49.926683+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=heroku-dev-antony.herokuapp.com request_id=4610f6f7-68bc-4cbc-94c2-bdaf052f1dce fwd="86.132.224.74" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-10-24T17:00:50.897033+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=heroku-dev-antony.herokuapp.com request_id=55c2a40c-6baa-4315-8b3e-2dc9d01c469c fwd="86.132.224.74" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

---

**Update 25 Oct 2016**

Ok so it turns out it was a simple beginner's mistake.
I basically deployed the whole kit (including `./src` and `./test`) to Heroku instead of only deploying the `./build` folder.

**Here are the steps for deploying your production React Starter Kit app to Heroku:**

*Requirements:*

- Have a Heroku account
- Follow the steps outlined here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-command-line

*Steps:*

1. Build the production-ready app using `npm run build -- --release`
2. `cd build`
3. Initialise a git repo with `git init`
4. Add everything with `git add .`
5. Commit your changes with `git commit -m "Commit message"`
6. Create a Heroku app with `heroku create my-apps-name-goes-here`
7. Push to Heroku `git push heroku master`

Voila!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the react starter kit doesn't run as production by default, and the buildpack [sets the environment to production](https://github.com/angelhive/react-starter-kit-buildpack/blob/master/bin/compile#L36). I believe that you can either add a [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) to the project telling it to start as production or simply [set the Heroku environment to development](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#custom-caching). If you post the Heroku logs when it errors, we could see more details of it.

Comment: Thanks andresk, I've set the `NODE_ENV` to `production` but the problem persists. :(

Comment: So, production is the default, you should try setting it to development

Comment: OK so I've set it to `development` and it works! andresk you're a lifesaver thanks a lot.

Comment: Although I do wonder if it's not a blow to performance to set a Heroku app to `development` mode with all the npm `devDependencies` to download. I'm saying this but I have no idea what's going on under the hood, just a general question.

Comment: When you set the environment as development it'll install all devDependencies on package.json, that's probably why it works when you use it. While you are developing and testing there is no problem at all. But if you intend to go prod, then you must setup your project so it will run with the minimum requirements possible

Comment: (I did not go through the entire react starter kit, but probably there should be a way to start it in production mode)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your edit — if you wished to deploy from the whole repo, here is the way to do that:

You have to add a `postinstall` script to your `package.json` that builds the project (if you put `npm build -- --release` in your Procfile it would be limited to 30s, after which Heroku would have terminated it — as a post-install script it has, IIRC, 15 minutes to execute).

Then, put only `web: node ./build/server.js` in the Procfile.

Also make sure NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION is set to false in your Heroku settings, so that devDependencies are downloaded.

Here's an example post-install script:

```
import run from './run';

async function deployOnHeroku() {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production') {
    process.argv.push('--release');
    await run(require('./build')); 
  }
}

export default deployOnHeroku;
```